# Static Variables inside EAR module and Jars within that EAR

Tags: java, logging

we have static variables in one of the java files of EAR module and we are initializing those variables via init() method. We have another jar which contains some other helper classes and methods within that jar  are  called from the EAR module itself. Now this jar also have a class file which have same static variables and these variables are again initialized  via init() method. the varaible names are same as were given in EAR module. So When i was working with this scenario in my EAR file , i found that variables values get overwrite once the code flows thru that jar. my question here is if i have a different package structure in the jar will it help?

the class file which is same is my log file and i am initializing my log appender in that class file. I have the same package structure in EAR module and jar file.

Comment: You have 2 classes with the same name and package? If you change one of them, then it will work naturally...

Comment: Here is the complete Scenario :
I had one module X.ear which had few EJBs and other helper classes plus jar files for helpers.It had its own log4jX file. It had one Log file which was used for initializing my loggers. now I took out my EJBs from this X.ear module and place it inside a new Y.ear . Now i want the logs of my new EAR module into new logs files. so i prepared a new log4jY file . but the jar which are required by my EJB classes still have LOG.java classes within them. Some have the same package structure but jar file had different package structure.

Comment: so when the code flows via that jar file my logs again starts going to the old log files.

Comment: Log4j settings are static, so this is as expected. You shouldn't package log4j.properties/xml files into the jars in the first place. If that is not an option, then the log files depends on the classloading order, which apparently loads the settings from the jars later.